# Java JFrame .setSize(x, y) not working?

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe

When I execute this bit of code, a tiny window pops up that, and the inside of it is about 116x63, and the entire size including the border of ~140x100. How do I set the inside to be what I need it to?

```
public static void graphics() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    String title = "test window";
    frame.setTitle(title);

    frame.setSize(gridRow, gridCol); //101 x 101
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a custom component, extending from `JPanel`, override its `getPreferredSize` method to return the size of the window you would like.
2. Either add this to your frame or set it as the frame's content pane.
3. Call `pack` on the frame

### Updated with example

[image]

On my PC, the `Frame size = java.awt.Dimension[width=216,height=238]`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFrameSize01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrameSize01();
    }

    public TestFrameSize01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                System.out.println("Frame size = " + frame.getSize());
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            String text = getWidth() + "x" + getHeight();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a ton of code for just a single window... thanks. :)

Comment: Well, if it's all about GUIs per LOC, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) with 10 & 1/3 LOC per GUI. ;)

Comment: Most of the code is here to demonstrate the point - showing that the inner viewable area is 200x200