# Java setBackground not working

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, setbackground

I am making a Game in Java, currently the set background doesn't work, but the setforeground works. Here is my code for the main class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sam extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(1920, 1080, 32, 60);
    Sam s = new Sam();
    s.run(dm);
}
public void run(DisplayMode dm){
    this.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

    Screen s = new Screen();
    try{
        s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }finally{
        s.restoreScreen();
    }
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("THIS IS GUNNA BE AWESOME", 200, 200);
}

}
```

here is the code for my Screen class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Screen {

private GraphicsDevice vc;

public Screen(){
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
}
public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window){
    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

    if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
        try{
            vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
public Window getFullScreenWindow(){
    return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
}
public void restoreScreen(){
    Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(w != null){
        w.dispose();
    }
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JFrame` is a composite component, it's actually made up of a number of other components

[image]

(From [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html))

So, when you call `setBackground`, you're only changing the background color of the underlying frame, not the `contentPane` which resides on it.

Instead, you should be using `getContent().setBackground(...)`.

*"But why does `setForegound` work*" I here you ask?

That's because you've overriding `paint` of `JFrame`, which is pre-configured with the `foreground` property of the frame (and not the `contentPane`)

Now, having said all that...

1. You should avoid extending from top level containers like `JFrame`, for these types of reasons AND...
2. You shouldn't override `paint` of them either. You should start with a component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.

Have a look at:

- [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319)
- [Graphics rendering in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131)
- [Java JFrame .setSize(x, y) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473627/java-jframe-setsizex-y-not-working/16473639#16473639)
- [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914)

for things that go wrong when you override `paint` of top level containers, and also, they aren't double buffered, so updating them causes flickering

## Example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Sam extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(1920, 1080, 32, 60);
                Sam s = new Sam();
                s.run(dm);
            }
        });
    }

    public Sam() {
        add(new MainView());
    }

    public void run(DisplayMode dm) {

        Screen s = new Screen();
        s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                s.restoreScreen();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public class MainView extends JPanel {

        public MainView() {
            this.setBackground(Color.PINK);
            this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            String text = "THIS IS GUNNA BE AWESOME";
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g.drawString(text, x, y);
        }

    }

    public class Screen {

        private GraphicsDevice vc;

        public Screen() {
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        }

        public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window) {
            window.setUndecorated(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

            if (dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
                try {
                    vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public Window getFullScreenWindow() {
            return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
        }

        public void restoreScreen() {
            Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
            if (w != null) {
                w.dispose();
            }
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getContent() does not work, getContentPane() works but it still does not change the color the the background

Comment: Did you get rid of the `paint` method, you're breaking the paint chain contract

Comment: Ok, I got rid of it, but how to I add the text then?

Comment: Create a `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent`, add your custom painting there (probably also set the background color of the panel to the desired color), add this to you frame...as I said

Comment: I have the paintComponent method in an overridden class, but how do I add it the frame;