# Java 'Background' opens to small to see anything

Tags: java, swing

I am making a game and the game window will only open to the size of the title. Please let me know what changes I need to make the "b.setSize(900,885)" work. I will change or add any amount of code if needed.

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import java.awt.Rectangle;
 import java.awt.Window;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

 import javax.swing.*;


 public class Background extends JFrame implements KeyListener,    ActionListener{
 int platform1X = 300, platform1Y = 555, platform2X, platform2Y;
 Image image;
 public boolean isJumping = false;
 int playerx = 100, playery = 585, velX = 0, velY = 0;
 public boolean[] keyDown = new boolean[4];
 private int fallingSpeed = 0;
 private int gravity = 5;
 private int jumpPower = -30;


 public Background(){

 addKeyListener(this);
 setFocusable(true);
 setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
 keyDown[0] = false;
 keyDown[1] = false;
 keyDown[2] = false;
 keyDown[3] = false;

 }
  public void paint(Graphics g){
 if(!isOnGround()){
 fall();
}
 ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("/Users/kairotieremorton/Documents/java   code/Kairo and Enoch Game/src/images/Backgroundsquareman.png");
image = i.getImage();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 900, 700, null);
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillRect(platform1X, platform1Y, 120, 20);
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillRect(playerx, playery, 30, 30);
try {
Thread.sleep(40);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} 


repaint();
playery = playery + velY;
playerx = playerx + velX; 
}



public static void main(String[] args){
Background b = new Background();
b.setTitle("Game");
b.setSize(900,885);
b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
b.setVisible(true);
}



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
int key = e.getKeyCode(); 
if(isOnGround() && key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
 keyDown[0] = true; 

 jump();

 }
 //if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){ setvelY(5); keyDown[1] = true;}
 if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) { setvelX(-5); keyDown[2] = true;}
 if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) { setvelX(5); keyDown[3] = true;}
 System.out.println(key);
 System.out.println(playerx);
 System.out.println(playery);
 }

 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
 int key = e.getKeyCode();

 if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){ keyDown[0] = false;}    //tempObject.setVelY(0);
//if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) keyDown[1] = false;//tempObject.setVelY(0);
 if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) keyDown[2] = false;//tempObject.setVelX(0);
 if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) keyDown[3] = false; //tempObject.setVelX(0);

 //vertical movement
 if(!keyDown[0]) setvelY(0); System.out.println(isOnGround());

//horizontal movement
if(!keyDown[2] && !keyDown[3]) setvelX(0);
 }
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 //playery = playery + velY;
 //playerx = playerx + velX; 
 //repaint();
 }
 public boolean isOnGround(){
 if(playery + (30 /2) >= 585) {
     return true;
 }
 return false;

 }

 public void fall(){
 playery = playery + fallingSpeed;
 fallingSpeed = fallingSpeed + gravity;

 }
 public void jump(){
 fallingSpeed = jumpPower;
 fall();
 }

 public void setvelX(int velX) {
 this.velX = velX;
 }
 public void setvelY(int velY) {
 this.velY = velY;
 }
 public float getvelX(){
 return velX;
 } 
 public float getvelY(){
 return velY;
 }
 public int getplayerx(){
 return playerx;
 }
 public int getplayery(){
 return playery;
 }
 public void setplayerx(int playerx) {
 this.playerx = playerx;
}
public void setplayery(int playery) {
this.playery = playery;
}
public Rectangle getBounds(){
return new Rectangle(getplatform1X(), platform1Y(), 120, 20);
}
public int getplatform1X(){
return platform1X;
}
public int platform1Y(){
return platform1Y;
}

public Rectangle getBoundsTop(){
return new Rectangle(getplayerx() + 10, getplayery(), 30 - 20, 5);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsBottom(){
return new Rectangle(getplayerx() + 10, getplayery() + 30 - 5, 30 - 20, 5);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsLeft(){
return new Rectangle(getplayerx(), getplayery()+10, 5, 30 -20);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsRigth(){
return new Rectangle(getplayerx() + 30 - 5, getplayery()+10, 5, 30 - 20);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

A better way to achieve the same result is to call b.setPreferredSize(dimension); and then pack() your frame.

See this answer for more information about JFrame.pack() :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22982334/5224040

Try this in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Background b = new Background();
    Dimension d = new Dimension(900, 885); //Create a new Dimension
    b.setTitle("Game");
    b.setPreferredSize(d);  //Set the PreferredSize;
    b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    b.pack();  //Pack the frame
    b.setVisible(true);  //Setting Visible
}
```

You can also use the following methods to reposition your frame as necessary:

```
b.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //center the location on the screen.

b.setLocation(0, 0); //Set location explicitly
```

Call either of these methods below b.pack(); to reposition your frame.

Comment: @KairoMorton Except, instead of been at `0x0`, the frame is located at  `300x555`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, that took a lot of looking, but...

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(getplatform1X(), platform1Y(), 120, 20);
}
```

is your problem.  [`JFrame#getBounds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBounds()) is a method used by `JFrame` to return the position and the size of the component and since you've overridden it, it will now ignore any values you pass to `setSize` (directly or indirectly)

Have a read of the following for reasons why you shouldn't override `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`

- [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319)
- [Graphics rendering in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131)
- [Java JFrame .setSize(x, y) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473627/java-jframe-setsizex-y-not-working/16473639#16473639)
- [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914)

As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid extending from `JFrame`, as you're not really adding any new functionality to the class, it locks you into a single use case and, based on your experience, can cause other problems.

You should start with something like `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method instead (and make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting)

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

You paint methods should run as fast as possible, so you should avoid loading resources like loading images, within the paint method

Swing is single threaded, so calling `Thread.sleep` in the `paint` method will cause the entire program to stop, including it's ability to respond to new events from the user.

I'd also discourage you from using `KeyListener`, using the key bindings API will be more reliable. Take a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: Where should i load the images to instead of the paint method

Comment: Preload the image, in constructor for example